# SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error (thrown under tomcat, but works fine in desktop)

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, sslexception

When I apply that code in a desktop application:

```java
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 WebRequest wreq = new WebRequest( new URL (url), com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod.GET);
 HtmlPage p = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage( wreq);
```

it works fine, I get an answer:

```
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 5D                                     ....]
[Raw read]: length = 93
```

(and then proceed with handshake)

But when I try to use exactly the same code within a web-application in a tomcat, it shows that error:

```
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 50                                              .P
tt_20170131_142449, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
tt_20170131_142449, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
tt_20170131_142449, called closeSocket()
tt_20170131_142449, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
```

TLS versions are the same. I tried some things usually suggested in that case, like webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL( false) and so on, but, as I said, that doesn't look like a protocol issue due to excatly the same code works perfectly while running without a tomcat. So where should I dig to find a solution?

Also there are different lenght of MD5 and SHA1 hashes:

[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 161   <--- cause an exception

[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 213   <--- works fine

Comment: Do the tomcat server and the local app use the same JVM?? Or at least, the same version with the same configuration??

Comment: Both of them use the same JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing httpclient-4.3.1.jar with 4.3.3 version.